# Remove list item with animation on list item button click event in android

Tags: android, listview, animation, baseadapter

I have a list view with custom adapter. In adapter there is a delete button with each list item.
When user click on delete button that item will be deleted from list.

I want animation while list item is remove. I have googled but all example are show animation on list item click event from activity class, but i want to animation view from adapter when adapter item button is click.

Below is my code on button click -

```
 mViewHolder.mDeleteIB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final Button ib = (Button)view;
            final int pos = (int)ib.getTag();
             mList.remove(pos);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
  });
```

below is my animation code -

```
 Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext,
            R.anim.slide_left);
 animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            mList.remove(pos);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
  vi.startAnimation(animation);
```

did not geting how to apply this animation on adapter child.

Please provide your valuable suggestions.
TIA

Comment: if you use recycler view you will get some default animation for add/remove functionality

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i have list with parallax effect. Is this possible to achieve this in recycle view.

Comment: https://github.com/kanytu/android-parallax-recyclerview see this

Comment: i have replaced my list with recycle view. can you please help me how to add animation while remov item in this.

Comment: It should have a default animation for deleting items

Comment: it removes item very fast. can we slow down it.

Comment: https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/RecyclerViewItemAnimators see this